# What is the overhead associated with std::condition_variable_any

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I have read in many places that there is some overhead associated with `std::condition_variable_any`.  Just wondering, what is this overhead?

My guess here is that since this is a generic condition variable that can work with any type of lock, it requires a manually rolled implementation of waiting (perhaps with another condition_variable and mutex or futex, or something similar) so the extra overhead probably comes from that?  But not sure...  As opposed to just being a native wrapper around `pthread_cond_wait()` (and equivalent on other systems) etc.

---

As a followup, if I was say implementing something that waits on, say, a shared mutex, then is this type of condition variable a bad choice because of the performance overhead?  What else can I do in this situation?

Comment: Why do you have to guess when the source code of at least two major implementations is freely available?

Comment: If you need the features of `condition_variable_any`, you need it. Otherwise use the plain `condition_variable`, if that's what you need. It is unlikely that we can come up with a simple and extremely fast method that the standard library implementers haven't thought of.

Comment: on vc++, there is an overhead - the cv_any allocates its state on a shared ptr, and when you wait on it, it duplicates the pointer, locks both your given lock and it's own inter-created lock. but as commented above, if you need cv_any, I guess there's no way around it.

Comment: @DavidHaim having some trouble understanding this, why does the lock have to be wrapped in a shared_ptr?  The lifetime of the lock should be valid till the lifetime of the condition variable right?  Why extend its lifetime?

Comment: Because that mutex ("lock") needs to outlive the condition variable, thanks to [thread.condition.condvarany]/5.

Comment: @T.C. Are there good usecases for that?  I can imagine where that might be useful, but the specification is hidden away where I did not look (I'm guessing most people don't know about this either?) Also I feel like most programs take care to manually ensure the condition variable and mutex have the appropriate lifetimes..

Comment: I'm talking about the `std::mutex` used internally by the `condition_variable_any`, not the ones passed by the user; the user has no direct control over the internal mutex's lifetime. As to why, presumably it does that because plain `condition_variable` does that, and plain `condition_variable` does that because pthreads condition variables do that.

Comment: @T.C. yeah I got which mutex the standard was talking about.  How does `std::condition_variable` ensure the lifetime of the associated mutex is shared across the threads that are calling wait on the condition variable?

Comment: `std::condition_variable` is just a thin wrapper around `pthread_cond_t` or equivalent. It has no internal mutex to manage.

Comment: @T.C. I may have miscommunicated but I meant to say this - how do pthread condition variables and mutexes do that?  Their lifetimes are managed manually right?

Comment: @Curious Do what, exactly?

Answer (score 5):

`pthread_cond_wait()` / `SleepConditionVariableSRW()`, same as the the plain `std::condition_variable::wait()` require just a single, atomic syscall for both releasing the mutex, waiting for the condition variable and re-aquiring the mutex. The thread immediately goes to sleep and another thread - ideally one which was blocked by the mutex - can take over immediately on the same core.

With `std::condition_variable_any`, the unlock of the passed `BasicLockable` and starting to wait on the native event / condition is more than just a single syscall, it's invoking the `unlock()` method on the `BasicLockable` first and only then issues the syscall for waiting. So you have at least the overhead from the separate `unlock()`, plus you are more likely to trigger an less than ideal scheduling decision on the OS side. Worst case, the unlock even caused continuation of a waiting thread on a different core, with all the associated overhead.

The other way around, e.g. on spurious wakes, there are also OS side scheduling optimizations possible when dealing with a native mutex (as used in `std::mutex`) which don't apply with a generic `BasicLockable`.

Both involve some book keeping, in order to provide `notify_all()` logic (it's actually one event / condition per waiting thread) as well as the guarantees about all methods being atomic, so they both come with a small overhead anyway.

The real overhead comes from how well the OS can make a good scheduling decision on the combined signal-and-wait-and-lock syscall. If the OS isn't smart about the scheduling, then it makes virtually no difference.